# PWA-app: Is it possible to turn on torch/flash of the camera from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, camera, windows-runtime, progressive-web-apps

I have created a "Progressive Web App" based on JavaScript with Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. I want to turn on the torch from JavaScript. I have implemented following code to show the camera:

```
var cam = Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUI(); 
cam.captureFileAsync(Windows.Media.Capture.CameraCaptureUIMode.photo) 
    .done(function (data) { 
        if (data) 
        { 
        } 
    }, function() {
    });
```

How I can turn on the torch from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs I understand that you only can set the following configs: AllowCropping, CroppedAspectRatio, CroppedSizeInPixels, Format and MaxResolution.

You can check the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.capture.cameracaptureuiphotocapturesettings

I think the function that you are asking for is not suitable for every phone, for that reason it is not a implemented functionality.